# Finfet Device - Fin thickness vs Channel length

Tags: mosfet, finfet

[image: Finfet]

I dont understand why fin thickness has to be greater than channel length as stated below:

> As long as the fin thickness (body thickness), Tsi, is smaller than
>   Lg, the short-channel effects are well suppressed and the subthreshold
>   swing is basically the theoretical best case

Please help me explain why?
Thanks very much!

Comment: You have a diagram yet your text does not appear to relate to the dimension names on that diagram. Why?

Answer (score 1):

In [MOSFET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOSFET) one wants the gate electric field to control the channel and drain electric field should have a lesser effect on the channel. Otherwise it will not work as expected and will show a set of unwanted effects called [Short-channel Effects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-channel_effect).

In order to reduce the effect of drain field on channel, the gate length (or channel length) is usually made (45x) longer than oxide thickness for a planar structure. In case of a [FinFET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multigate_device#FinFET), the gate electric field is decided by the thickness of silicon fin (Tsi) and hence it is made smaller than the channel length or gate length (Lg).

Answer (score 0):

The answer has to do with "charge sharing" the source/drain edges.  FETs are as long as necessary to make them behave as FETs.  This is why 14nm is 20nm actual and 130nm is 80nm actual.  It completely has to do with process.    The best reference that I know for this is:

Fjeldly, T. and Shur, M., “Threshold voltage modeling and the subthreshold
regime of operationof short-channel MOSFETs,” IEEE Transactions on Electron
Devices, vol. 40, no. 1, pp. 137–145, 1993.

Even though that reference does not specifically describe what's going on in FinFETs, it describes the problem.  If you want some information specific to FinFETs, I would skim through the IEDM papers.

Of course, if you have access to the design kits for GF/Samsung/Intel FinFETs, there's usually a nice theoretical discussion on why this is.